# Order duplication for other customer

Tags: sales-order, order-duplication

I want to create a new order from an existing order `(cart, products...etc)`for other customers with a button "copy", Is it possible ?

**Edit :**

1. Imagine you have :

> Order n°10001 Customer name : Magento, email : magento@magento.fr ...etc Customer products : computer ASUS , speakers...
>
> Now you want to have exactly the same order with the other customer and the same products and with a different n° of order :
>
> Order n°10002 Customer name : Ninad, email : Ninad@magento.fr ...etc products : computer ASUS , speakers...

So, first question : Is it possible ?

2. If yes, how can i do this ? i just don't know how to begin to do this in fact...

Comment: What version of Magento is your question about?

Comment: magento 1.9 and 2.0 both